# how to stop downgrading while installing from deb

Tags: package-management

I used to install deb packages by using command: `dpkg -i *.deb` as all deb's are in same folder.

Sometimes dpkg shows warning of **Downgrading** dependencies to lower version. Because Later Version Already Installed.

So, How to Stop Downgrading (skip that package to install) so that Higher version remain installed.

Gdebi shows warning and stops From Installing. But It is Limited to handle single deb at a time. So Is there any command (dpkg --?) To skip that package While Group of debs installing?

Or Give me Antother Method To Install. (synaptic Add downloaded files Option  not working well in offline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `--refuse-downgrade` option so that no package is downgraded.
So run the following command to install packages.

```
dpkg -i --refuse-downgrade *
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even use the `--no-force-all` option since you can also encounter packages conflicting to each other, or forcing the package to be installed even if its dependencies are not satisfied, which might break your system.